# Todo comments:Not include and left align?

Tags: lists, margins, marginnote, todonotes, displaystyle

Is there a way to to do a \todo*{Hello} and not have the note show up in the ToDo and Notes area? Does anyone know how to do that? Or vise versa?

Also, what about in the left side margin instead. I think it would be easier to read and actually more manageable over there, than off to the left side.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Notepad}

% Comments and \todo notes package
\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{} % \cmmnt{}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3.5cm}
    % \todo{Comment}    % \todo[noline]{}   % \todo[inline]{}
    % \todo[color=red!50]{Revision}
    % \todo[color=blue!40]{Improve}
    % \todo[color=purple!50]{Nice}

\begin{document}   

\todo[color=red!50]{Revision}
\todo[color=blue!40]{Improve}
\todo[color=purple!50]{Nice}

\listoftodos[ToDo's and Notes]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `\reversemarginpar` to have notes on the left side of the page and `nolist` option to create a note not listed in the ToDo's and Notes area.

To create a note listed but not in the text, I propose to add an `inline, nolist` note after `\listoftodos` command, but I hope someone else will find a better solution!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Notepad}

% Comments and \todo notes package
\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{} % \cmmnt{}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}\reversemarginpar
%\reversemarginpar to have notes on the left margin (I have also modified the \marginparwidth otherwise the notes go out of the page)
% \todo{Comment}    % \todo[noline]{}   % \todo[inline]{}
% \todo[color=red!50]{Revision}
% \todo[color=blue!40]{Improve}
% \todo[color=purple!50]{Nice}

\begin{document}   

    \todo[color=red!50]{Revision}
    \todo[color=blue!40]{Improve}
    \todo[color=purple!50]{Nice}
    \todo[color=yellow, nolist]{Note not listed in the ToDo's and Notes area}

    \listoftodos[ToDo's and Notes]
    \todo[color=white,inline, nolist]{I don't know how to create a note in the list but not in the text}
    \todo[color=white,inline, nolist]{I hope someone else will help you, if you don't like this solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lady Friend! If two extra lines is all, then all is good!

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to remove the border around the notes, you may use `bordercolor=white`: `\todo[color=white, bordercolor=white, inline, nolist]{Your note}`. Thank you for having accepted my answer!