# Add post-it style sidenotes to a document

Tags: comments, notes, sidenotes

How can post-it style sidenotes be added in a document? I like to use it for temporary comments on my thesis.

Comment: Maybe `todonotes` package could help you, see [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316220/todo-commentsnot-include-and-left-align/317305#317305) for example.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for (and even more). Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy you have found it useful!